# Convert an object into a string within a method in R

Tags: r, string, loops

It is very simple.

```
v = c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for (i in v) {
function(data = df, ..., main = "here comes a text and \v")
}
```

The question is, how can I ensure that v appears there? I know that Swift has this `\()` command where you can pass that through within a string.

**Edit**
`paste`solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `paste()`?

```
v = c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for (i in v) {
function(data = df, ..., main = paste("here comes a text and",v))
}
```

This will make `main` equal to `Here comes a text and var1`, `Here comes a text and var2` and `here comes a text and var3`.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks!

Comment: that would be a different question about the code in the function itself ..